# git clone issue with copssh

Tags: git, github, clone, github-for-windows

Using copssh,I've set up my own git server whose os is windows 2012.
And I've created one git repository.
[The git repository directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzquM.png)

As you can see in the image, there is one git repository named "vacationsabroad.git"

In my local pc, I'm gonna clone this repository. 
So I use the following command.

```
 git clone administrator@myserverip:/cygdrive/c/cossh/home/admin/git/vacationsabroad.git
```

But I've gotten the fatal error:

> fatal: '/cygdrive/c/cossh/home/admin/git/vacationsabroad.git' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

[Error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M05o3.png)

How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the copssh and git server, maybe you have to use the following command.

```
To check out a repository: git clone {username}@{servername}:{repodriveletter}:/{repopath}
```

So your command could be like this.

```
git clone administrator@myserverip:c:/cossh/home/admin/git/vacationsabroad.git
```

Hope it will help you. If it doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: also don't forget to put quotes if you have spaces in your path.